port 6432 failed: FATAL: SASL authentication failed
I am a beginner in postgresql. I want to manage connections to my postgresql database using pgbouncer. I have done all the necessary configuration but I get this error:
**psql: error: connection to server at “localhost” (127.0.0.1), port 6432 failed: FATAL: server login failed: wrong password type
**

This is the content of the file that I have configured
I want to manage connections to my postgresql database using pgbouncer.
